# Why isn't "satisfactory" considered a correct answer to this question?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following question is from a practice test:

> Tentative, fearful even, his first forays into the theatrical arts were hardly __________.

I have to "Select exactly two words that best complete the sentence and produce sentences that are alike in meaning" from this list:

> 1. auspicious
> 2. commendable
> 3. unpropitious
> 4. satisfactory
> 5. favorable

The correct answers are given as *auspicious* and *favorable*.

It seems to me that the clue in this sentence is where it says “tentative, fearful”.  If his attempts to enter were *tentative* and *fearful*, then they were hardly promising.  And two similar words to promising are *auspicious* and *favorable*.

If we find them to be *hardly promising* then why isn't *satisfactory* a correct answer?

Comment: You should note that the instructions are *"Select exactly two words that best complete the sentence and produce sentences that are alike in meaning."*

Comment: You have not got me. What would be the problem if I choose commendable and satisfactory?

Comment: Presumably, in the view of the test designers, *commendable* and *satisfactory* are not as close in meaning as *favorable* and *auspicious* are. Here are some definitions: **satisfactory:** acceptable, though not outstanding or perfect. **commendable:** deserving praise. **favorable:** to the advantage of someone or something. **auspicious:** conducive to success; favorable.

Comment: It's actually a clever question.  The two answers that you selected are partially correct.  This is an example of what is called a "distractor" in test preparation parlance.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Hardly [auspicious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auspicious)*: indicating that future successes were unlikely.
2. *Hardly [commendable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commendable)*: deserving more blame than praise.
3. *Hardly [unpropitious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unpropitious)*: rather good, rather favorable.
4. *Hardly [satisfactory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/satisfactory)*: rather unsatisfactory, unsuccessful.
5. *Hardly [favorable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/favorable)*: rather unsuccessful, rather bad.

*Unpropitious* is a clear odd man out: it is negative (so the combination with *hardly* is positive), whereas the other adjectives are all positive.

*Commendable* is also different from the other three in that it has a mandatory moral connotation which the other three lack.

I disagree with the official answer that considers *favorable* to be closer to *auspicious* than to *satisfactory*, but it's a close call. *Auspicious* is always about future expectations, it is synonymous to *promising*. To say that the forays were *auspicious* would mean that future successes were likely. *Favorable* does not really have that connotation in common usage: it would be perfectly acceptable to say that his initial forays were *favorable* or not without implying anything about future attempts. This is closer to the meaning of *satisfactory*. While *satisfactory* implies middling results (not bad, but not very good either) which does not match *favorable* (good results), the negations are synonymous: results that are *hardly satisfactory* or *hardly favorable* are mediocre to bad without being extremely bad.

*Favorable* can also be interpreted as meaning *auspicious*, but this is not the most obvious meaning of the word. So I find this exercise flawed because it is ambiguous.

Comment: I would only add that an actor making a foray into the theatre, does not seek to be satisfactory. The desire is to achieve the audience's favour and the event to be auspicious. For this reason, I agree that the right words are auspicious and favourable.